# bash: compgen -c does not return me the output that I want

Tags: command-line, bash

```
compgen -c | sort -b | uniq | less
```

Shows also functions and keywords (luckily no aliases), I instead want all that are not keywords, functions or aliases. In few words only the commands.

If command name match with function name, keyword name or alias name; the command name must not be omitted.

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) first. For example `compgen -a` to return aliases

Comment: `compgen -c` instead shown also functions and keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `compgen` (and I think [for Linux in general](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shell_commands#Bash_and_Command_Types)), a command is everything that you can run including alias' and functions, etc.

If you want to get only executable files/scripts in any of your `$PATH` directories, there is no good way using `compgen`.

You could use `comm` to show all commands excluding aliases, keywords and functions:

```bsh
comm -23 \
  <(compgen -c | sort -u) \
  <(compgen -akA function | sort -u)
```

However, this will also remove commands that are both alias/function and command (e.g. `ls` or `grep` have an alias per default in Ubuntu, as well as anything you added yourself).

So, I think you're better off getting all executables from `$PATH` with your own script (and if you wish you can add `builtins` using `compgen -b`):

```bsh
path_filenames(){
  printf '%s' "$PATH" \
  | xargs -d: -I{} -- find -L {} -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -printf '%P\n' 2>/dev/null
}

sort -u <(path_filenames) <(compgen -b)
```

Comment: I have declared a function named `sudo` and another named `apt`. With this method, commands that are also functions are omitted.

Comment: True, also things like `ls` won't show because they also have an alias in Ubuntu. See the alternative, that should work better for you

Comment: Yes. This is a perfect approach, not for exclusion but for inclusion. I have found a simile answers that I not have understand. `echo -n $PATH | xargs -d : -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 \
        -executable -type f -printf '%P\n'`

Comment: What is the uppercase "%P" in "printf"? On internet I have found `File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.` but there are no examples and I did not understand what this explanation means.

Comment: What is %P?....

Comment: your solution misses the `-L` which is important, because many files in $PATH are actually symlinks.

Comment: In one of my previous comments I wrote that I did not understand the explanation `File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.` as no example of its meaning is provided.

Comment: It means write the filename only, discard the path. so `/usr/bin/grep` will output as `grep`.

Comment: What is means the curly brackets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120339/discussion-between-plumo-and-mario-palumbo).

Comment: YESSSS! GREAT! THANK YOU! I HAVE UNDERSTAND ALL!

Comment: with `comm -2` it works also.

Comment: For the first solution there are 3042 commands, while in the second one there are 2926 commands. Who have reason between these two solutions?
How to show the differences between the 2?

Comment: I have verified that the second one have reason and not the first. The first solution have also aliases and functions showed. My command list have 2926 command really

Comment: with `comm -23` instead we are closer to the solution: 2916 the first and 2926 the second one, but in this case the commands that have the same name of functions, aliases and keywords are also removed (in my case 10). Ultimately the first solution is not valid in any case.

Comment: true. I clarified my answer.... I don't think it's possible with `compgen` then.

Answer (score 0):

To print **aliases**, run:

```
alias
```

To print **functions**, run:

```
declare -F
```

or

```
declare -f
```

To print **commands** ( excluding **aliases**, **keywords** and **functions** ), run:

```
compgen -c | \
grep -wv "$(alias | grep -oP '\w+(?=\=)')"| \
grep -wv "$(declare -F | awk '{print $3}')" | \
grep -wFv "$(compgen -k)"
```

- `grep -wv "$(alias | grep -oP '\w+(?=\=)')"` will exclude aliases.
- `grep -wv "$(declare -F | awk '{print $3}')"` will exclude functions.
- `grep -wFv "$(compgen -k)"` will exclude keywords.

Comment: I want to show all commands and not functions, aliases or keywords. Sorry for bad explain.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo I updated the answer with that.

Comment: Aliases do not already appear in the default command `compgen -c`, the thing that unfortunately appears are the keywords, which have not been removed with your command.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo I updated the last command to exclude **keywords** as well.

Comment: I think this has the same problem as my first solution then, it removes commands that are also aliases (e.g. `ls`) or functions.

Comment: @pLumo **No,** it matches whole words ie. if an alias or a function is named for example `lsl`, the command  `ls` will still be printed in the output.

Comment: I don't mean `lsl`. But `ls` is also an alias in Ubuntu by default (see `grep "alias ls" /etc/skel/.bashrc` --> `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`). And that is not shown in your output then.

Comment: @pLumo :) Now I am interested in this question: **Why would you do that?** that is not normal and you are probably most likely certainly better off without that kind of alias.

Comment: This is default in ubuntu, so yes, I guess there are some people that do that ... why not, it's not a different behavior, only nicer output. Same for `grep` --> `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`.

Comment: @pLumo Sorry but **No,** again `/etc/skel/.bashrc` does not get processed in my answer. To get what I mean run just `alias` .... It's a built in command.

Comment: But `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is exactly your `.bashrc` right after ubuntu installation --> the default. If you don't change it by yourself, you have these also in the output of `alias` (I do).

Comment: @pLumo You are **correct**. I see what you mean. **+1**